# Insert records on picklist selection visualforce page

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I have to display multiselect list in vf page. Upon selection of no of items in the list and clicking save button that many items will be inserted into a object.

For Ex - I have a multiselect list with values as M1, M2,M3. If i select all the 3 values and click save button, 3 records will be created with Name M1, M2, M3 in an object.

Can anyone explain or share some code sample.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="cont">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedOptions}" multiselect="true" size="3">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class cont {
    public List<String> selectedOptions {get; set;}
    public List<Custom_Object__c> customObjList {get; set;}
    public cont() {
        selectedOptions = List<String>();
        customObjList = new List<Custom_Object__c>();
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('M1','M1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('M2','M2'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('M3','M3'));
        return options;
    }       
    public void save() {
        for(String option : selectedOptions) {
            customObjList.add(new Custom_Object__c(name = option));
        }
        if(customObjList != NULL && customObjList.size() > 0)
            insert customObjList;
    }
}
```

**Assumptions:**

1. Custom Object to be inserted is having API Name Custom_Object__c
2. Its not having any fields except Name field(If you want to insert any other fields you can add them aswell)

Hope it helps.